# Updating only the changed values in an object when long polling entire list of objects in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I'm constantly long polling a list of servers:

```
var servers = ko.observableArray();
$.getJSON('/Home/GetServers', function (data) {
    servers.removeAll();
    $.each(data, function (xxx) {
        servers.push(new Server(xxx);
    });
});
function Server(xxx) {
   var self = this;
   ko.mapping.fromJS(xxx, {}, self);    
}
```

and I have a list of objects as an observableArray and I only want to change the values of the objects that have changed, rather than removing all and re-pushing every element.

Comment: See the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) for the mapping plugin. Specifically the part relating to keys. Or keep a dictionary of some key and the server object so you can check if it already exists.